# Event Listener for this scenario

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. I have been reading up about event listeners, but I don't know or where to apply it to my code.

I am trying to build a very basic calculator. A user will enter two amounts into two different HTML fields, and it must count the two together. My code is working, except that it doesn't update the final amount once the field values are changed, so I need an event listener. How will I use it in this scenario? I've looked at samples online but it hasn't helped me much.

Am I supposed to put some of my code in a function?

*Note: My final global variable called "paytotal" needs to always show the updated results so that I can use this variable anywhere on my page.*

My Javascript:

```
var payamount1 = document.getElementById("amount1").value;
var payamount2 = document.getElementById("amount2").value;
var paytotal = Number(payamount1) + Number(payamount2);
document.getElementById("payment-due").innerHTML = paytotal;
```

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="amount1" placeholder="enter amount 1">
<input type="text" id="amount2" placeholder="enter amount 2">

<div class="details-row">Total payable: <span id="payment-due"></span></div>
```

Comment: Please show your attempt at implementing an event listener to perform this logic.

Comment: You should put your JS in a function and call that function when the inputs change

Comment: A couple of unrelated tips: Don't set a variable equal to the value of an element property as you are doing with the `.value` of the two amount elements. If you ever decide that you'd like to access a different property, you'd have to scan the document again for the same element(s) you already scanned once for. Instead, set your variables to the element themselves and then when you need a property, you can just get it from the element variable (i.e. `payamount1.value` or `payamount2.classList`).

Comment: Also, don't use `.innerHTML` when the string you are working with doesn't contain any HTML. `.innerHTML` has security and performance implications and should generally be avoided. Use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: Lastly, while converting a string to a number using `Number()` certainly works, you can accomplish the conversion easier by just prepending a `+` to the string that needs conversion, like this: `var paytotal = +payamount1 + payamount2`.

Comment: Thank you @ScottMarcus you gave me some incredibility useful tips. I'm very new to javascript. This helps me so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an eventlistener on both input-fields and call there a function (calc) in which you have included your code.

```js
var amount1 = document.getElementById("amount1");
var amount2 = document.getElementById("amount2")
amount1.addEventListener('change', calc);
amount2.addEventListener('change', calc);

function calc() {
    var payamount1 = amount1.value;
    var payamount2 = amount2.value;
    var paytotal = Number(payamount1) + Number(payamount2);
    
    document.getElementById("payment-due").innerHTML = paytotal;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="amount1" placeholder="enter amount 1">
<input type="text" id="amount2" placeholder="enter amount 2">
<div class="details-row">Total payable: <span id="payment-due"></span></div>
```

Comment: I like this solution, but then my variables will no longer be global variables. Any way around it?

Comment: @Shtarley I changed it, now your variables are global i.e. the amount1.value can't be global because the value had to be read out just after you made an input, so it had to be in the calc-function.

Answer (score 2):

Event listeners `listen` to when something happens. In your case, the best event to listen to is `input` as it will detect everything that you need.

For simplicity, I would give your inputs a class.

And for the javascript this will add the input listener to the inputs.

```js
    var amounts = document.querySelectorAll(".amounts");
    var paytotal = 0;
    amounts.forEach(function(el){
      el.addEventListener("input",function(){
       var payamount1 = document.getElementById("amount1").value;
       var payamount2 = document.getElementById("amount2").value;
        paytotal = Number(payamount1) + Number(payamount2);
       document.getElementById("payment-due").innerHTML = paytotal;
    });
    });
```

```html
    <input class="amounts" type="text" id="amount1" placeholder="enter amount 1">
    <input class="amounts" type="text" id="amount2" placeholder="enter amount 2">



<div id="payment-due"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

lots of ways to do this.  here's one; Be sure to check your result is not NaN

```js
function addUp() {


  var payamount1 = document.getElementById("amount1").value;
  var payamount2 = document.getElementById("amount2").value;

  if (payamount1 != '' && payamount2 != '') {
    var paytotal = Number(payamount1) + Number(payamount2);
    
    
    
    if(!Number.isNaN(paytotal))document.getElementById("payment-due").innerHTML = paytotal;
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="amount1" placeholder="enter amount 1" onchange="addUp()">
<input type="text" id="amount2" placeholder="enter amount 2" onchange="addUp()">
<div class="details-row">Total payable: <span id="payment-due"></span></div>
```